# https for facebook applications

Tags: ssl, facebook

Read a lot about the new guidelines for facebook developer, 
but i got know real answer about this:

1. Do I realy need a https-website to get an app running?
2. Anyone got it running via ssl-proxy?

Thx Sven

Answer (score 0):

Not really a stackoverflow.com question, nor is this (1) something not covered by Facebook already (see http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/497/). In short, yes, you must have SSL-ready server.

As for (2) stackoverflow.com is not a platform meant to advertise products. Your most likely answer is http://godaddy.com (personally not using any godaddy.com services and would not recommend them for any other reason that price).

There are a lot of alternatives, e.g. http://networksolutions.com, http://rapidssl.com (see http://www.cheapssls.com/ for more offers).

Comment: Sometimes there are hacks out there which could allow developers to by-pass the rule. So I think it's valid for Sven to ask the question 1. For questions 2 you can answer it technically like "google free cheap ssl" etc. :)

Comment: Ew. "by passing https"? Don't even want to imagine what that could mean. Theoretically one could use `https://` redirect service. That's just not an advice I would give to a friend.

Comment: hrm... I mean by passing facebook rules, not by passing https... anyway your first sentence in your answer may discourage people from asking questions. just saying.

Comment: @Unreality and so they should be discouraged to post questions that either been covered multiple times or generally don't go with SOF.